# Clojure eval causes garbage collector to hang

Tags: clojure, garbage-collection, eval, metaspace

I encounter this problem when running a genetic programming algorithm which uses eval.

To illustrate the problem, I narrowed it down to the following code fragment:

```
(loop []
  (do 
    (eval (list '+ (rand) (rand)))
    (recur)))
```

When I run the code the garbage collector unloads all the created $eval_n classes once from metaspace but on the second garbage collector invocation it hangs.

I use jdk1.8.0_102 with the follwing JVM options:
-XX:MetaspaceSize=200m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=200m

After a while I get the following error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace, compiling:(form-init2581690491924993906.clj:1:1)
```

**EDIT:**
I added a screenshot of visualVM to show the behaviour, when the JVM hangs, the graph is not updated anymore, and it keeps using a full CPU core.

[image]

I also tried it using java 7 (without any JMV options), and I encounter the same problem with PermGen.

Any ideas how to avoid this problem?

**EDIT:**

The problem only occurs when I run it from a leinigen-REPL with eclipse-counterclockwise. If I run the code from a basic command line REPL the problem does not occur!

Comment: Just wondering, how do you know that "[it hangs] on the second garbage collector invocation"? And how do you run this code to get the error? I cannot reproduce it. Could you provide the exact commands?

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers, I added a screenshot of the VisualVM graphs.

Comment: Thanks. I installed this program and ran your loop from Emacs with Cider in the REPL on Java 1.7.0_80. It runs fine and the garbage collection cycles are consistent. See http://i.imgur.com/wHYEmII.png.

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers thanks for you effort. I wonder why you graph does not show any variance in the number of loaded classes.

Comment: In what way do you run the code?

Comment: the default is `MaxMetaspaceSize                          = 18446744073709547520 ` ... you're giving it less, any reason for that?

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers good question! I encounter the problem when ran it from eclipse with the counterclockwise plugin within a repl started from leiningen. I just tried running it directly from the command line the jvm does not hang! So it must be a problem with either leiningen or counterclockwise I suppose...

Comment: @the8472: If I give it the default, the problem shows up at a later time. I gave it less MaxMetaspaceSize to be able to reproduce the problem more quickly.

Comment: @DennisvandenBerg it is probably related to Counterclockwise then since I do not have the problem and also use Leiningen, but not Counterclockwise.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed steadily increasing memory consumption with the above example. Adding a System/gc

```
(loop [] (do (eval (list '+ (rand) (rand))) (System/gc)) (recur))
```

doubled CPU consumption but kept memory usage at what looked like a long term steady state.

Comment: Yes, but calling System/gc that frequently causes the program to be really slow, so I do not think this is a real solution. The VM should handle the gc itself.

Answer (score 0):

I concluded this problem is not directly related to clojure eval or the JVM. It only occurs in combination with eclipse-counterclockwise and/or a leiningen-REPL.